# How to fix live debugging for flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, debugging

I am fairly new to flutter development.

I am using vs code and windows 11. I am trying to live debug using usb to my phone. It is a Huawei p20 pro that still uses android.

I've tried most solutions from the net but flutter still DOES NOT find my device.
USB debugging is on. I have huawei hi suite connected. I've tried different usb cables as well. I've changed the ports that the cable is connected to.

I don't plan on using android studio.

Please help. Thank you

I've tried most solutions from the net but flutter still DOES NOT find my device.

USB debugging is on. I have huawei hi suite connected. I've tried different usb cables as well. I've changed the ports that the cable is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Install adb drivers for windows 11

Use adb command to check if device is connected or not ( you need platform-tools to run adb command, if not download it)

```
adb devices

or

./adb devices
```

Make sure usb debugging notification showing on your phone when connected to PC

check the list of devices on bottom right corner of vscode if your device is present or not